# Comparing two json schemas

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm looking to determine whether two highly nested json objects have the same schema. What I was thinking of doing was to get a list of all keys recursive and compare them. For example:

```
def get_all_keys_recursively(d, keys=None):
    LIMIT = 400

    if keys is None: keys = []
    if len(keys) >= LIMIT: return keys

    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
          get_all_keys_recursively(v, keys=keys)
        else:
          keys.append(k)
    return keys
```

Would there be a better way to do this, or does the above seem like a good approach?

Comment: If by "better" you mean more efficient, then there are most likely better ways.  One more obvious one being a case where json1 is empty, and json2 has 399 keys. There is no need to loop through all of json2, store the keys in memory, and then do your compare.  But without more context it's difficult to say what the best approach will be.  Also, does python guarantee ordering when looping through dict keys?

Comment: Are you trying to check if every key in the first dictionary appears in the second dictionary, and vice versa? Or are you trying to check if both the keys are the same and the structure is similar i.e the nesting is the same across both?